# Spring : Controller and Service Layer coding standard example

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, coding-style, service-layer

I am checking out my project code and found below method in controller. On the net I found that `controller` is for receive request and provide response. `Service` Layer is for Business Logic and `Dao` layer is for data CRUD related operation.

In below method I can see business logic. Now I am not getting which code should be moved to service layer or below is fine.

I am reviewing code so I need to provide comments but I am confused.

```
       @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/app", method = RequestMethod.POST)
       public ModelAndView saveApp(
                 @ModelAttribute("application") @Validated Application application,
                 BindingResult result) {

          ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
          ApplicationFormValidator formValidation = new ApplicationFormValidator();
          boolean messageFlag = false;
          String operationalStatus = null;
          formValidation.validate(application, result);
          if (result.hasErrors()) {
                 model.addObject(APPLICATION, application);
                 model.setViewName(ADD_APP);

          } else {
                 if(checkActive(application)){

                                status = FormBeanValidator.encodeStatus(application.getStatus());
                       application.setStatus(status);
                       // calling service layer and convert model into entity
                       messageFlag = applicationService.addApp(application);

                       if (messageFlag) {
                              Application applicationForm = new Application();
                              applicationForm.setSuccessMessage(PropertyHandler.getPropertyInstance().getPropertyValue(Constants.SUCCESS_MESSAGE));
                              model.addObject(APPLICATION, applicationForm);
                              model.setViewName(ADD_APP);


                       } else {
                              application.setErrorMessage(PropertyHandler.getPropertyInstance().getPropertyValue(Constants.ERROR_MESSAGE));
                              model.addObject(APPLICATION, application);
                              model.setViewName(ADD_APP);

                       }

                 }
                 else{
                        application.setErrorMessage(PropertyHandler.getPropertyInstance().getPropertyValue(Constants.OTHER));
                       model.addObject(APPLICATION, application);
                       model.setViewName(ADD_APP);
                 }
          }
          return model;
   }
```

Comment: The only questionably part to me would be : `if(checkActive(application)){
   status = FormBeanValidator.encodeStatus(application.getStatus());`. But I see there already is a separation : `applicationService.addApp(application)` so that might be enough

Comment: my question is even that "if" check ie if(checkActive(application)) should be in controller or not. As this is a business logic.

Comment: Well, it depends on what `checkActive` does. If it implies a strong business logic, you should move it to the service layer.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine,but I would suggest some modifications:

1) Your `checkActive(application)` seems to check something about your business object(application),so move it to the service layer.You could merge your `checkActive()` method logic by moving the `checkActive()` method into service layer and calling it inside your  `applicationService.addApp(application)` as a local method.

2) You have been setting the view name as same in both the `if` as well as `else` block.Try and move this code out  of the if-else block as it becomes redundant.

3) It is a practice to send only the required data from the controller to the view.This is done by creating a DTO(Data Transfer Object) and making a Converter class which maps your business object fields to the DTO.You can look for example use case for DTO [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine if you are checking for null or incorrect format validation inside your  `ApplicationFormValidator`